# Complex SQL query with an alias

Tags: mysql, sql, alias

I saw this complex select statement that has several components: aliases and subqueries

```
SELECT
    u.ID, u.username, u.active, u.email, u.admin, u.banned, u.name,
    (SELECT
        GROUP_CONCAT( g.name SEPARATOR'-groupsep-' ) FROM groups g,
        group_memberships gm
        WHERE g.ID = gm.group AND gm.user = u.ID
    ) AS groupmemberships
    FROM users u WHERE u.ID={$uid}
```

The part that doesn't make sense to me is the part `AS groupmemberships`.

What is it aliasing? The element that follows `u.name`?

I unfamiliar with subquery syntax.

Any useful explanation and a link to official documentation would help.

Comment: The alias means *"...and give it this name."*  The name can be referred to elsewhere in the query.  See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp) for additional explanation.

Comment: Yes, it is aliasing the element that follows uname, which would be the result of the correlated subquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query is using a subquery in the `FROM` clause of the query. The subquery returns a set of rows which is in turn used as a table by the rest of the query. In MySQL, it is mandatory to give an alias to this 'virtual table'.

So concretely, the name `groupmemberships` refers to the result set from

```
   SELECT
       GROUP_CONCAT( g.name SEPARATOR'-groupsep-' )
   FROM
       groups g, group_memberships gm
   WHERE
       g.ID = gm.group
       AND gm.user = u.ID
```

A more detailed explanation can be found in [the MySQL documentation about subqueries in the FROM clause](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/from-clause-subqueries.html).

Answer (score 1):

From the [Mysql manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/from-clause-subqueries.html)

> Subqueries are legal in a SELECT statement's FROM clause. The actual syntax is:
>
> SELECT ... FROM (subquery) [AS] name ...
>
> The [AS] name clause is mandatory, because every table in a FROM clause must have a name.

So basically I can give my resulting table a name and use it in the outer query as a table itself.

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

It's the column name for the result of the subquery. No different to say

```
Select V1,V2,(V1 + V2) As Total From SomeTableOfVs
```